# Parser Error when trying to implement CKEditor in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I'm trying to implement `CKEditor` to my ASP.NET website. I copied the ckeditor folder with all its files and bin folder with CKEditor.NET.dll file and pasted everything into my website's directory,as described in the [codeproject website](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/532164/How-to-Integrate-CKEditor-with-ASP-NET)

However I keep getting this error while opening the index page:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CkEditor' or one of its dependencies.
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot
be loaded.
```

This is how the registry line looks like:

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

I am using vs2005 with .net framework 3.5 installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by directly downloading the CKEditor from the the link http://ckeditor.com/download.

Sorry for disturbing you guys.Also dont forget to mention the path of the ckeditor as in the project.